# Will destroying a second empire title give independence to kingdoms?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I currently have 2 empire titles. My main one is all good and I intend to keep it. My second one however managed to get a elective succession law installed and by the looks of things my heir will not be voted in. This means that my empire will split apart upon by death.

I have realized that I need to destroy this second empire title in order to remove the possibility that my empire split. However when I destroy it the 2 kingdoms currently in that empire become independent.

Why those kingdoms became independent? Is there an alternative solution to my problem?

By the way I am not running the latest version of the game, I have 2.4.1.

Comment: Are the holders of the titles to the two kingdoms your direct vassals?

Comment: @sommerjj Yes both of them are

Comment: I would try transferring the empire title to your heir, or both kingdom titles. I'm not sure why destroying the titles grants independence but by directly giving your heir the title to the empire you should avoid losing it during succession

Comment: @sommerjj Thanks bro thats a good solution for now

Answer (score 1):

No, they will not become independent. As long as they are your vassals, they will stay your vassals until they die, rebel, you die or you give them independence.

In case of *your* death, independence can only happen if you are over your vassal limit, and they're not in the de-jure territory of your primary title ('first' empire) that you control. They can go independent (or rather, their heirs) if they are de-jure part of 2nd empire.